# How to set blink time on GTK3 tooltip?

Tags: c, tooltip, gtk3

I want to change the blink time (in order to make it shorter) that a tooltip has in a GTK3 graphic application I am developing. I have done some research, but I did not found the proper way to do this. 
Please, let me know if there is a simple way to do this. All information is welcomed.

Comment: Looks like [no](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkSettings.html#GtkSettings--gtk-tooltip-timeout)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much.